# SQL query on timestamp interval: optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization

I am getting stuck by the execution time of a query. I have a table (no written by me) with a lot of rows (4mio) and a column representing the timestamp.
I want to do a query that will keep only the datas between two given timestamp.

I am currently using :

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE timestamp BETWEEN "x" AND "y"
```

This query takes approximatively 11 sec to return 4000 row, while the query without the WHERE statement but a limit of 50'000 rows is executed in less than 0.1 sec. I am aware of the fact that with the WHERE statement, more rows are tested.

Because the timestamp is always increasing, is there any way to stop the query if the upperbound of the timestamp is reached? Or another way to run the same query much more faster?

Thank you very much

Kilian

Comment: Add an index to the timestamp column. And only return the columns you really need

Comment: As "juergen d" said. Can you provide the table definition please?

Comment: @Giles I updated the post with the table definition.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  The png you provided does not tell us whether DayTimeStamp is _first_ in a composite index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE NumberModule=24 AND Timestamp BETWEEN 40764 AND 40772
```

Needs a different index:

```
INDEX(NumberModule, Timestamp)
```

My [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) discusses why.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see all the indexes, plus the ENGINE.

Comment: I have created the index according to your discussion and the request works well now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add an BTREE index (best way to deal with `BETWEEN`, see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html)):

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD INDEX myIdx USING BTREE (`timestamp`)
```

Please post the result of

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN "x" AND "y"
```

after that.

Comment: thank you for the reply. The index was already here as a BTREE. On the definition of the index, there is :
type: BTREE
Unique: no
columns: DayTimeStamp NotValid
 

id:1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: results
type : ALL
possible_keys: DayTimeStamp_Idx
key: NULL
key_len : NULL
ref: NULL
rows: 3524658
extra: using where

Comment: So your index is not used (key: NULL). Try a hash-index: `ALTER TABLE myTable ADD INDEX myIdx USING HASH (timestamp)`

Comment: the key is still NULL. If I put a LIMIT 50000 at the end of the query, then the key is used...

Comment: Is it used if you say `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE timestamp > 200` ?

Comment: it is not. (I didn't implement the bd so I am quiet sorry I am not very aware of what is happening)

Comment: Can you post the original query you test with?

Comment: In fact, the key is used if the difference between the two timestamp is not too big.
between 40290 AND 40300 : used
between 40290 AND 40400 : not used

Comment: Perhaps your index statistics are outdated (lots of DELETE, UPDATE statements on Table since creating). Try a `OPTIMIZE TABLE myTable`, this will re-calc the statistics

Comment: It is running much faster now. But the problem remains when I add a new WHERE clause. For example, if I do:
    SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE NumberModule=24 AND Timestamp BETWEEN 40764 AND 40772
it takes again 11 sec...

Comment: Always do an `EXPLAIN SELECE ...` to see what INDICES are uses. The run-time is a bad indicator, the number of rows in your EXPLAIN-result is mutch better. Try to bring this number down by adding indices on your columns used in the `WHERE` part. See the MySQL docs for a detailed description on the EXPLAIN output. Be aware of the possibility to add more than one col in an index.

Comment: @Benvorth - HASH does not exist; it is turned into BTree.  Anyway, BTree can handle ranges; Hash cannot.

Comment: @Benvorth -- `ANALYZE TABLE` is a much faster way to recalc stats than `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.